# Parabolic(?) projectile orbits as an approximation to elliptical orbits given a rotating Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, projectile, drag, approximations

Why is projectile motion a parabola given that the Earth rotates and a parabola is an approximation to an orbit.

My current thought is that projectiles don't travel in a parabola because if the Earth were not rotating, they would actually, given Newton's Law of Gravity (F=GMm/r^2), be an approximation to part of a very long ellipse. However, since the Earth is rotating, they aren't quite. The exact specifications of the ellipse are quite complex, due to the angular momentum it interacts with, of the Earth and of the Earth's orbit about the Sun, which both cause precession (not really important on that time scale). There is also, more importantly, but still not very, the drift due to the rotation of the Earth's surface relative to the reference frame of the ellipse's orbit, I believe. PRIMARILY, there is the air resistance. Of course, the air resistance is almost entirely in the reference frame of the Earth's rotation, though there may be wind or turbulence. So I am analyzing this to death.

I entered this into Wolfram Alpha (out of laziness): (radius of the earth)*2 * pi * 4 seconds/(24 hours)

Because I know that 4 seconds is a rather long time for a projectile at normal heights and distances (normally more like 2 seconds), based on endless physics problems while tutoring and teaching.

It says, 1.15 miles or 1.85 km.

Obviously that is WAY too much drift. If nothing stabalizes it, the Earth's rotation would carry a projectile far far off its path at the Earth's equator.

Perhaps the atmosphere ties it into the Earth's rotational frame at the Earth's surface?

Edit:

I do know this is called coriolis force. I don't know why it is so large. I am trying to make sense of how it changes as one leaves the atmosphere: for example, why is an airplane flying at a steady rate not on an orbit? Or is it? Why do orbits have specific speeds while airplanes and cars can vary their speeds?

Edit again:

I mean "why is a ball thrown on a parabola", then?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the Earth's rotation, but you are correct that the parabola is an approximation.  It's the solution when $\vec{F}=-mg\hat{y}$ instead of $\vec{F}=-\hat{r}GMm/r^2$, which is only valid near the surface of the Earth for altitudes much less than the radius of the Earth $y\ll R_E$.

Comment: the parabola is an exact mathematical result assuming that the gravitational force is constant and down, and the earth's surface is flat. It has nothing to do with rotation. The approximation is good enough for small range projectiles

Comment: I know it's exact if gravity is constant and down. But that is not how gravity actually works. I know the orbit is a parabola in an innertial reference frame, to a good approximation. But the Earth rotates relative to an innertial reference frame in that time, by a substantial amount. So what stabalizes the path to a near parabola? I know it's not an exact parabola, but why does it seem to be off by a half mile to a mile?

Comment: Aha! I was just talking to a friend who helped with this. Between the two of us and your input, we made some progress. Thank you both of you for helping as well. I partially understand now. It sounds like the reason it follows a parabola at earth's surface is because at earth's surface, the gravity is approximately constant. The velocity is then relative to earth's surface, and the linear velocity is approximately what matters, since earth is approximately flat locally. In other words, compared to the rotating earth, the effective initial velocity of the ball is much higher so it goes further

Comment: Continuing on that question, though. An orbiting object is in an inertial reference frame. The surface of the earth is not, as viewed from orbit. But up close, the surface of the earth appears to be an inertial reference frame, as seen by the projectile. I really hadn't expected that. I know about the equivalence principle in GR, but I hadn't expected it on non-geodesics like the surface of the earth or a parabola relative to it. What sort of semi-inertial reference frame is that?